# Mex file output (more than one)

Tags: file, variables, mex

I have created a mex file which works fine when is called with only an output argument, but it gives me the next output when called with more than one:

> ??? Error using ==> mtimes Too many output arguments.

I manage the output arguments in the mex function like shown next:

```
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] ) { 
mxArray *FirstTerm,*SecondTerm,*ThirdTerm,..

....

FirstTerm                       = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(N,M,mxCOMPLEX);
FirstTermRe                     = mxGetPr(FirstTerm);
FirstTermIm                     = mxGetPi(FirstTerm);

SecondTerm                      = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(N,M,mxCOMPLEX);
SecondTermRe                    = mxGetPr(SecondTerm);
SecondTermIm                    = mxGetPi(SecondTerm);

ThirdTerm                       = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(N,M,mxCOMPLEX);
ThirdTermRe                     = mxGetPr(ThirdTerm);
ThirdTermIm                     = mxGetPi(ThirdTerm);
....
....

plhs[0] =FirstTerm; 
plhs[1] =SecondTerm; 
plhs[2] =ThirdTerm;

}
```

When called as next:

```
function_mex(input_arguments)
```

it generates a single output variable.

When called with two output arguments, as next:

```
[x,y]=function_mex(input_arguments)
```

it gives me the message:

> ??? Error using ==> mtimes Too many output arguments.

I just do not know why that error. This is the way I did it in some mex files some time ago, and they worked correctly.

May anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking to make sure that the number of outputs specified by matlab is equal to 3 because your mex-file is creating 3 outputs and spitting out 3 outputs.  That's the easiest way to make sure that matlab doesn't complain about the number of outputs.